# Extracting Columns in Excel having multiple number formats

Tags: excel, numbers, format, copy-paste

I have a report on web that can be downloaded. On the same column I found multiple formatting style for the numbers. i.e:

1.000 EA  (#,##0.000" EA")

1.000 AU  (#,##0.000" AU")

1.000 PAK  (#,##0.000" PAK")

I need to extract EA, PAK and AU from this column but I cannot copy as the values stored are actually "1" in all cases. Is there any way I can extract or create a column that has the different formatted numbers as values?c

Comment: @Ralph, I think he wants to get the format as text in a column. Not copy the format. It probably isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Yes it does seem to be similar. I have not used vba codes. Can you explain where I need to do this. Or can this be a cell value in any way?

Comment: Oh, in that case you are probably looking for `=CELL("format",A1)`, right? If that doesn't help then you'll have to write some VBA code (because this cannot be achieved an Excel formula only). The VBA code will include a loop and `.NumberFormat`.

Comment: @Ralph That did not give the correct format. It gave me ",3"

Comment: Then you'll have to write a VBA based solution (as mentioned in my comment above). Of course you can also make use of the UDF solution offered by @nightcrawler23. But I (personally) wouldn't as this solution will severely impact the performance of your Excel and might also not give you the desired results (as these functions don't update as often as you might think they do).

Comment: agreed with @Ralph. But since the OP is new to VBA coding, i kept code to a minimum :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in a module in the VB Editor(<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F11</kbd>)

```
Function myFormat(r As Range) As String
    myFormat = r.NumberFormat
End Function
```

if you use the formula `=myFormat(A1)` in a cell, it will give you the format of the cell `A1` as string.

Now in a desired cell put this formula

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(myFormat(A1), LEN(myFormat(A1)) - FIND("""",myFormat(A1),1)),"""",""))
```

This should give you the desired results

**Update:**

Below is an all vba solution. You need to change `myRange` and `outputRange` as per your requirement

```
Sub runThis()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3") 'Change this as per your requirement

    Dim outputRange As Range
    Set outputRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1") 'Change this as per your requirement

    Dim s As String

    For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        s = myRange(i, 1).NumberFormat
        s = Right(s, Len(s) - WorksheetFunction.Find("""", s, 1))
        s = Trim(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(s, """", ""))
        outputRange.Offset(i - 1, 0) = s
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check what happens if you use your formula like this: `=myFormat("A1:B5")`?

Comment: @Ralph what is need to do that? BTW, i added a vba solution :D

Comment: The VBA solution generates run-time errors whenever the number format does not contain `"` because you are using `WorksheetFunction.Find` instead of `InStr()` and `WorksheetFunction.Substitute` instead of `Replace()`.